# Prepend one value to a list 'x' number of times

Tags: c#

I want to add a value multiple times at the beginning of a list, what I have is...

```
internal static class Helper
{
  public static void Prepend(this IList<double> source, double value, int count)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
      source.Insert( 0, value );
    }
  }
}
```

Then use it as follow

```
// create
var mylist = new List(){ ... };  // create the list
mylist.Prepend( 0, 10 );  // prepend 0 to the list
```

But I wonder if there isn't a more efficient way of doing the same thing?

Comment: If count is greater than source then it might be more efficient to append  the source to the count

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is there a reason you use `IList`? because `List` has the `InsertRange` method which uses `Array.Copy` amongst other optimizations.

If we need to support `IList`,  we don't want to depend upon implementation details and `IList.Insert` sounds like your best option.

Another approach is you could check whether the actual implementation is `List` and use the `InsertRange` method or fallback to `Insert` in a loop.

Example of adding the items using `InsertRange`

```
var items = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10);
source.InsertRange(0, items);
```

Comment: Yes, it could be a `List`, but I am not sure I understand `InsertRange`, I would I be able to add 'x' numbers at the beginning of the list using `InsertRange`?

Comment: @SimonGoodman no, it allows you to add a range of values in one call. Therefore, you should build your list of duplicate value first. I have updated the answer with an example.

Comment: @Paparazzi it is, otherwise the `.NET` implementation would not use `Array.Copy` and use the the for loop as fallback.

Comment: I see now, I didn't know about the `Enumerable.Repeat`, that's why I wasn't sure how `InsertRange` would work in that case.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about performance the most generic solution would be to use `Concat` and not to modify the original list at all. Usually you don't want to do it but return a new collection instead.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T value, int count)
{
    return Enumerable.Repeat(value, count).Concat(source);
}
```

---

> ```
> var mylist = new List(){ ... };  // create the list
> ```

If you really create a list and prepend more items to it right away in the next step then combinding the the constructor with the collection initializer is another option that might work for you:

```
var result = new List<int>(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10)) { 2, 3, 4 };
```

Comment: Important to consider difference between `IEnumerable<T>` and `List<T>`. I would expect an extension method on the former to return a new `IEnumerable<T>` and would expect the latter to mutate the `List<T>` instance.

Comment: @t3chb0t thanks, to answer your question, the list is created much earlier in the process.